# Webots: How to fix a base_link in simulation

Tags: simulation, webots

So I set up a simulation of a robotic arm in Webots. However, the collisions between the `base_link` and the `ground_plane` seems to cause Errors when the mesh of the `base_link` becomes more complicated than a simple shape.

At the moment I have solved it by simplifying the geometry of the `base_link`, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution. I know some other simulators have a form of `fix_model` or `fix_base_link` option to avoid having to calculate collision with the `ground_plane` for static objects. Does Webots have something similair?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, usually for robotics arms, the base link is attached to the static environment as described in the first point of [this answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/24050/17975).

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://cyberbotics.com).*